# MySQL: Низкая производительность запроса конкатенации строк столбца

Tags: mysql

Я делаю серверное приложение для проверки пароля на сложность.

В базе данных MySQL у меня есть таблица содержащая около 100 тысяч популярных паролей.
Например:

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  words    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 123456    |
|  2 | password  |
|  3 | 12345678  |
|  4 | qwerty    |
| .............. |
+----+-----------+
```

Пользователь вводит пароль "`132password443`". В базе данных должно быть найдено соответствие, в данном случае ему соответствует "`password`".

Мне приходится делать запрос через конкатенацию строк столбца, что показывает очень медленную производительность:

```
SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE '132password443' LIKE CONCAT('%',words,'%')
```

Я хотел бы увеличить скорость выполнения запросов, но не знаю как это сделать! Возможно, есть более рациональный запрос к базе данных?

Или может быть, посоветуете использовать какой-нибудь другой движок базы данных, где проще реализовать такую выборку?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ни один движок БД не имеет серьёзных средств оптимизации для поиска подстроки в строке. Максимум возможного - замена LIKE на `WHERE LOCATE(word,password) > 0`, тоже не очень, но хотя бы накладные расходы поменьше... Используйте внешний поисковый движок.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо за рекомендацию! А что за внешние поисковые движки вы имеете в виду? Какие, например?

Comment: Sphinx, ElasticSearch и т.п.

Comment: @Akina, Спасибо!

Comment: @Akina Установил Sphinx, начал разбираться, оказывается он не поддерживает ни `CONCAT ('%',words,'%')`, ни  `LOCATE(word,password) > 0`. Может быть есть другие решения?

Comment: *оказывается он не поддерживает* Substring search - присутствует.

Comment: @Akina, Исходя из документации Sphinx имеет очень много опций, как на уровне конфига, так и на уровне самих запросов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть?